# Easier way to scale controls?

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

Recently I coded an extremely graphical interface in for hi-res displays(1900x1200). Of course my the requirements changed, and it needed to be redone in 1366x768. Rather than retool the app for a fixed resolution(lesson learned), i moved everything into its own ViewBox and recrafted my grid controls to handle this. The app looks great and scales to (nearly)any size without artifacts.

My question is, is there an easier way to accomplish full dynamic control scaling in WPF with putting each control in its own viewbox? ViewBox was the only control I could find to do this, but it can only contain one child element, which made this a VERY tedious process. Is there a better control that can contain child controls that scales?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not put a Grid or StackPanel inside the viewBox, and then fill them with the controls?

[image: Big hello s]

Something like this

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:WfpApplication1="clr-namespace:WfpApplication1"

    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

<Viewbox>
    <StackPanel>
        <CheckBox Content="Hello World!"/>
        <TextBlock Text="Hello world"/>
        <Button Content="Hello world!"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Viewbox>
```

Comment: Don't know why i didn't think of this lol...still new to WPF and I forget about the flexibility of nesting objects within others. I tried this method and it would definitly work and is much more user friendly, but it seems to produce a different behavior than the method I used. Either way, this is the answer i needed.